# Lookup Function SSRS 3 datasets

Tags: reporting-services

I have 3 datasets in a report where I need to run a lookup to bridge common data between.  I can look up the owner's IDs when it's kept in 2 datasets with:

```
=Lookup(Fields!DatabaseName.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!OwnerID.Value, "DataSet2")
```

What I've tried so far without success for connecting that 3rd dataset and returning owner names is the following:

```
=Lookup(Fields!DatabaseName.Value & Fields!Source_Worker_ID.Value, Fields!Name.Value & Fields!OwnerID.Value, Fields!Full_Name.Value, "DataSet3")
```

Dataset 1 contains DatabaseName (It's all the DBs I need to patch).

Dataset 2 contains Name (Same as DatabaseName) and OwnerID (Owners I'll need to contact for scheduling).

Dataset 3 contains Source_Worker_ID (Same as OwnerID) and Full_Name (Employee Names).

My end goal is to return the owner IDs from DS 2 related to all DBs in DS 1 with a lookup(Or other function), then return all the names from DS 3 for those IDs found during the first lookup.

Does anyone have any ideas on making this lookup work?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to do a `lookup` within a `lookup` which is going to perform like a dog.  Can you not `join` this data in your source dataset query?

Comment: The data is on 3 seperate servers so I can't run a join on any of the dataset queries, unless there's a method to do that which I'm unaware of.  I'm willing to have it perform slow, so long as it's not unbearably slow.  It's just a report that'll run ad hoc, so no need for blazing speeds.  Can you provide an example of a lookup in a lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

I apologize. You're right. I was unaware of the fact that Nested lookups is not possible. BUT, there is another way you could do it.

1. Add a textbox to your report.
2. Give the textbox the following expression:

`LOOKUP(Fields!DatabaseName.Value, Fields!DatabaseName.Value, Fields!OwnerID.Value, "Dataset2")`

3. Right click on the textbox -> Textbox Properties -> Visibility -> Select Hide
4. Go to the text box in question and add this expression:

`LOOKUP(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value, Fields!Source_Worker_ID.Value, Fields!Full_Name.Value, "Dataset3")`

Tell me if this works.

**Explanation:**

A `LOOKUP` function only takes 4 arguments.

1. Source Expression: This is the field in the first and primary dataset that you are going to use to find values of other fields in other dataset. In your case, `DatabaseName`.
2. Destination Expression: This is the name of the field you are going to match your first field with. In your case, since `Dataset2` has the same column name as `Dataset1` (`DatabaseName`), it will be `DatabaseName` again.
3. Destination Value: This is the value corresponding to the given destination expression you are hoping to get. Since you want the `OwnerID` for any given `DatabaseName`, you need the `OwnerID` as the third parameter.
4. Data set: This is the dataset you are trying to look for this value at. In your case, its `Dataset2` (or `dataset3`).

You can play with only these 4 arguments.

**Explanation 2**

It is important to remember that you can ONLY connect from your primary dataset to other datasets. If your report is being built from `Dataset1`, you can lookup values in ALL OTHER datasets USING `Dataset1`. You cannot lookup value in `Dataset3` using a value from `Dataset2`. That is why you need a `lookup` to find the value from `Dataset2` and use it to find a value in `Dataset3`.

**DEMO:**

In this image:

[image]

the first column that has a 5 digit number is from `DataSet1`. The second column with a 2 digit number is the field `Location` from `DataSet2`. The third column with a name is the field `LocationName` from `DataSet3`.

Here is how these three datasets connect to each other:

[image]

Here are the lookup queries I used:

```
=LOOKUP(Fields!SORD.Value, Fields!ShopOrder.Value, Fields!Location.Value, "DataSet2")

=LOOKUP(ReportItems!Textbox4.Value, Fields!Location_ID.Value, Fields!Location_Name.Value, "DataSet3")
```

This seems to work fine for me. Here is what the table looks like:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my report data sources and shared data sources:

[image]

Are you doing something like this? I know this is a very simplified report and your situation might be much more complex, but your report needs to look something like this.

If none of this helps, I apologize. This is the only way I know how to do.

Comment: I actually had fiddled around with this on my first attempt as I'd thought the syntax would be similar to this considering experience with lookups in excel.  However, then and now, the error is the same.

              " The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox10.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains a Lookup or LookupSet function in the argument to another Lookup or LookupSet function. Lookup functions cannot be nested inside other lookup functions."                

Any suggestions?  It looks like I can't nest lookup functions.

Comment: I used the following:
=Lookup(Fields!DatabaseName.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!OwnerID.Value, "DataSet2")
=LOOKUP(ReportItems!Textbox12.Value, Fields!Source_Worker_ID.Value, Fields!Full_Name.Value, "Dataset3")

The first script was hittig DatabaseName twice so I had to fix it, the new textbox is named textbox12.  I got the following error:

" The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox10’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for a lookup function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is the name of a dataset."

Comment: Is this new textbox IN your table? I apologize, I should have been clearer about that. Try adding the first expression IN your table somewhere. If you have an empty cell in the table anywhere, add it in there.

Comment: It's in the table.  If I could add images to show, I would.  They're side by side in the table, with the owner ID yet to be hidden as I wanted to run some testing to make sure it's looking up correctly.

Comment: Is the first lookup working correctly? Just delete the second lookup and see if the first lookup works right.

Comment: I removed the "=" in the LOOKUP(ReportItems!Textbox12.Value, Fields!Source_Worker_ID.Value, Fields!Full_Name.Value, "Dataset3") so it would pull as plain text and the ownerids are pulling as expected.

Comment: Check the demo section of my answer. I tried doing it in a simple report and it works for me. See if yours looks something like this.

Comment: I don't know why and I don't know how, but changing it to spit something else out and then changing it back got rid of the error.  It didn't pull back for a bit but found one of my datasets needed to be rtrimmed.  It's working as it should now.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think that was because of this beautiful thing that MS decided to do called .data file. Usually, if you RUN the report instead of PREVIEW it, you would get an updated result. If you just preview it, the .data file does not update correctly. It just updates it half way and modifies the error to a different error because it still has the last error message from the last cache and it changes it just slightly to match the current version of the report. Don't ask why, it just does.